# How to disable Esper's avro.EventTypeAvroHandlerFactory warning

Tags: esper

Have no clue why I am getting these warnings when I run Esper. All my searches about these warnings WRT Esper have turned up blank.

```
37   [main] WARN  com.espertech.esper.common.internal.event.avro.EventTypeAvroHandlerFactory  - Avro provider com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl not instantiated, not enabling Avro support: Unable to load class 'com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl', class not found
341  [main] WARN  com.espertech.esper.common.internal.event.avro.EventTypeAvroHandlerFactory  - Avro provider com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl not instantiated, not enabling Avro support: Unable to load class 'com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl', class not found
1207 [main] WARN  com.espertech.esper.common.internal.event.avro.EventTypeAvroHandlerFactory  - Avro provider com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl not instantiated, not enabling Avro support: Unable to load class 'com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl', class not found
1722 [main] WARN  com.espertech.esper.common.internal.event.avro.EventTypeAvroHandlerFactory  - Avro provider com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl not instantiated, not enabling Avro support: Unable to load class 'com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl', class not found
1987 [main] WARN  com.espertech.esper.common.internal.event.avro.EventTypeAvroHandlerFactory  - Avro provider com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl not instantiated, not enabling Avro support: Unable to load class 'com.espertech.esper.common.internal.avro.core.EventTypeAvroHandlerImpl', class not found
```

Pretty standard Esper setup ...

```
    Configuration configuration = configuration();
    EPRuntime runtime = EPRuntimeProvider.getDefaultRuntime(configuration);
    EPEventService eventService = EPRuntimeProvider.getDefaultRuntime(configuration).getEventService();
```

Not using Avro as part of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugged where the warnings were coming from, and found that, by default, enable Avro is set to true.

A quick peek at the documentation echoed what I found in the debugger:

> The enable-avro setting is boolean-typed and is true by default. It controls
> whether Avro is enabled or disabled. If disabled the compiler and
> runtime disallow registering Avro event types or using an Avro event
> representation.

The following setting removes the warnings.

```
configuration.getCommon().getEventMeta().getAvroSettings().setEnableAvro(false);
```

Comment: Version 8.8 is the current version, is this using an old version?

Comment: 8.8 ... here is the link to the documentation from 8.8 quoted above (See section 17.4.9.2) http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.8.0/reference-esper/html_single/#configuration-common-eventmeta